# Can a non-SF project make use of the applicationmanifest configuration values?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I've got a Service Fabric Application set up in the following way:

```
Solution
--SF Project
  --ApplicationManifest.xml
--Stateless Project (uses app manifest values)
--Stateless Project (uses app manifest values)
--Class Library (used as a repository by the above two projects)
```

**How can I enable the class library to make use of the ApplicationManifest.xml configuration file from the SF Project?**

To allow the projects to be able to use the AppManifest for build/deployment, they simply need to be created like so:

[image]

**How does a project that does not get added as a Service Fabric project make use of the applicationmanifest?**

The Service Fabric projects are able to use the appmanifest by including parameters in settings.xml and servicemanifest (but non-SF projects cannot):

[image]

Comment: So... do you need to access the parameters defined in your service's settings.xml from non-SF project? is that what you're asking?

Comment: @KirylZ exactly yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1**

If you need to access the parameters defined in your service's setting.xml, the next should work -

1. In your non-SF project, install
   **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration** and **ServiceFabric.Extensions.Configuration** NuGet packages
2. Wherever you decide to access the parameters, use the next code snippet -

   ```
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddFabricConfiguration("Config");
   var configuration = builder.Build();
   var section = configuration.GetSection("MyConfigSection");
   var parameterValue = section["MyParameter"];
   ```

One note though - you will get access to only one SF service at a time. That's because AddFabricConfiguration() works by calling FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext(), which ties settings being loaded with the SF service you're calling a non-SF code from.

**Option #2**

Next option will work from any place where you could establish connection with the SF. Using code below, you could read any parameter passed into the app manifest -

```
var fClient = new FabricClient();
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric");
var manifest = XDocument.Parse(fClient.ApplicationManager.GetApplicationManifestAsync("YOUR_APP_TYPE_NAME", "YOUR_APP_TYPE_VERSION").Result);         
var parameterValue = manifest.XPathSelectElement("/ns:ApplicationManifest/ns:Parameters/ns:Parameter[@Name='PARAMETER_NAME']", namespaceManager).Attribute("DefaultValue").Value;
```